# How to make post request with params and body in Postman

Tags: postman

I have endpoint which takes few parameters and body as input, and I want to test it in Postman. But, when I input data into 'form-data' section in Postman backend throws error that I am missing body. If I try input data into 'raw' (Text) it complains that I forgot about parameters. How can I combine params and body?

EDIT:

1. 'form-data' section
   [image]
2. 'raw' section
   [image]

Parameters for that endpoint are following:

```
@RequestParam("to") String to,
@RequestParam("subject") String subject,
@RequestBody String content,
@RequestParam("isMultipart") Boolean isMultipart,
@RequestParam("isHtml") Boolean isHtml
```

Comment: Can you show and image of what you have in Postman. What's the error code that it's throwing? What details is the endpoint expecting? The question is a little vague.

Comment: It is not throwing error, but request received by backend missing required data, as I described above.

Comment: So a 400 Bad Request? Need to see what you have in Postman - Back up the words that you have with more information about the problem and images of what you're trying to send via Postman.

Comment: Yes, I noticed 'Status: 400 Bad Request'. In a moment I will provide screens.

Comment: More info about the parameters and the body that are required, would help too. Do you have some documentation that you've been given about what the valid values should be?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the request params you would add them to the end of the `URL` rather than in the request body, like you have done in the image.
`?to=random@email.com&subject=Testing mailing feature&isMultipart=false&isHTML=true`

This can be seen in the Postman UI when you select the `Params` button, this can be found next to the `Send` button.

[image: Params]

I'm unsure about the `string` that you need in the request body and in what format the endpoint requires this data.

If it's in a JSON format you could add `{"content": "Some new content"}` to the `raw` body and select `JSON (application/json)` from the dropdown, this will also set the correct request header.

**Edit:**

The UI has changed slightly since this answer was given. The `Params`tab is now placed in a less confusing place.

[image: New Location]

Comment: works, perfectly. In this case Postman is not intuitive. Thx!