# How to pass REST parameters of a function in Postman body

Tags: typescript, rest, postman, nestjs

Hello I'm writing a numbers multiplication code in NestJS where I pass REST parameters in a function. But I don't know how do I pass REST parameters in postman during API call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make post request with params and body in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675142/how-to-make-post-request-with-params-and-body-in-postman)

Comment: Can you possibly show what your NestJS controller and service (if you have one) looks like? It's a little vague on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve that, I'm just going to give an example of some of the most used.

**Path Params**

[image]

and your NestJS function (Controller) ex:

```
@Put(':id')
 update(@Param('id') id: string) {
   ...
}
```

**Query Params**

[image]

NestJS function (Controller) ex:

```
@Get()
getData(@Query() params: paramsDto) {
   ...
}
```

**Body Params**

[image]

NestJS function (Controller) ex:

```
@Post()
create(@Body() params: paramsDto) {
    ...
}
```